# JDBC ClassNotFoundException SQL Server 2008

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, servlets, jdbc, classnotfoundexception

So let me start out with the fact that the SQL Server JDBC Driver JAR file IS definitely in the build path for the Java Resources Folder:

```
Java Resources--->
        -Libraries
            * Apache...
            * EAR Libraries
            * JRE System Library
            * sqljdbc4.jar-C:\jdbc_connector ----->(where I saved the JAR)
            * Web Libraries
```

When I run a basic Java Application to see if the Driver is found and connection is made, it works:

```
public class DBConnect {

    private Connection conn;
    private Statement stmt;
    private ResultSet rs;

    public DBConnect() {
        super();
        try {

            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1;" +
                     "instance=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=my_DB;user=Dan;password=12345;");
            System.out.println("Connection Successful");

            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String select = "SELECT * from ROLES";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(select);
            while(rs.next()) {
                String id = rs.getString(1);
                String title = rs.getString(2);
                System.out.println(id + "   " + title);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Everything outputs as it should.

Once I try to connect in a Servlet, the Class throws a ClassNotFoundException on the JDBC Driver Class.forName(). The doGet() is supposed to be automagically called in the constructor so my constructor is empty other than the call to super(), for it extends HttpServlet.

```
public class LandingPage extends HttpServlet {

           public LandingPage() {
        super();

    }

           protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String resultSet = "";
        int index = 1;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1;" +
                    "instance=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=Timecard_DB;user=Dan;password=Mc177700;");

            out.println("<%@ page language='java' contentType='text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'");
            out.println("pageEncoding='ISO-8859-1'%>");
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
```

........................

And so on and so forth.

Can anyone help me figure out what I need to do? Thank you.

Comment: The driver JAR *is* in the *build* path, but is it deployed correctly? (I would guess not for the `ClassNotFoundException` to occur.) It should be located in one of those places: (1) The `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your application (2) The lib folder or the classpath of the application server (which one are you using?) (3) the system classpath (I doubt it is). Can you verify?

Comment: I am proficient with java but new to Java EE and Servlets. Whenever I have added external jar files in the past I have never had issues isolating specific directories to add to. For some reason when i attempt to store the sqljdbc4.jar in either the WEB-INF/lib folder or the apache folder, the .jar will configure, but only as deep as the Libraries directory in "Java Resources". How would configure the .jar into the WEB-INF/lib folder? When I attempt build path in that folder, it sends me to the "Orders and Exports tab of the Application properties. From there I cannot figure out the next step.

Comment: Can you provide more info on your evironment? IDE, application server?

Comment: Eclipse Kepler, Apache Tomcat 6.0 Server

Comment: Your project should be a dynamic web project (download the JEE version of eclipse or the WTP plugins/features). By default web resources are placed in a WebContent folder under the project. Create a WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder and place the driver jar there. If deploying from within Eclipse, it will get deployed automatically. If you want to create a WAR file to deploy manually, make sure you do it through Eclipse by right-clicking the project -> Export -> WAR file.

Comment: I think I may have bypassed the issue for the time being. Th jar file is still in the same directory, but I manually copied and pasted the jar into my tomcat/lib directory. Now that it is deployed there, the server is finding the class. Hopefully this does not pose any new issues. Thank you.

Comment: Actually this is a good directory to place the driver, because it is available server-wide. Now, I would suggest you to take a look at connection pooling - the DataSource class for your next step. Have fun!